# Footer overlaps login form in mobile landscape mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

I'm trying to create a login page for my application .It includes a header ,login form which is horizontally and vertically centered and a footer .Everything works fine in the normal mode but when i load it in mobile landscape mode footer overlaps the login form .Can anyone help me how to figure it out .I know the issue is due to fixed footer a the bottom but when i try to give position:absolute or position:relative the footer jumps near the header

```css
.full-width{width:100%;}
.login-container{position: absolute;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 330px;margin:auto;padding-bottom:100px;}
.parent {position:fixed;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);margin-top:60px}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed bottom-line" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
        aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand logoLinkStyle" href="#">
       <img [src]="'application/images/logo.png'" alt="Brand logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="parent">
<div class="row login-container">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
      <form name="form" #loginForm="ngForm" novalidate>
       <h1 class="welcomeheading">WELCOME</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control user"  name="username" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" required autofocus>
            </div>
         
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control"  placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" aria-label="Password" required>
           </div>        
          <button class="btn full-width"  [disabled]="loading">Login</button>
        <div class="login-forgot">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">Forgot your password?</a>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>    
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid"  style="position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12">
      <h6>Copyright (c) 2017 this is the copyright of application developed
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
      <img [src]="FooterLogo" alt="Footer logo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a media query and remove the absolute positioning on mobile.

You'd have to calculate your height breakpoint, but it would look something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  .parent, .login-container {
    position: static;
    transform: none;
  }

  .footer {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```